# NGINX returning 404 when visiting?

Tags: nginx, webserver, websites

NGINX throws 404 when I visit, and in my error logs it gives

```
/home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php" failed (13: permission denied)
```

I'm not sure why, this only happened when changing my direction to dropbox.

Running `ps -ef | grep nginx` outputs:

```
root 11373 5885 0 15:48 pts/0 00:00:00 sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
root 11374 11373 0 15:48 pts/0 00:00:00 nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
dev 11566 3392 0 15:55 ? 00:00:03 gedit /var/log/nginx/error.log 
root 11607 1 0 16:01 ? 00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on;master_process on; 
www-data 11608 11607 0 16:01 ? 00:00:00 nginx:
worker process 
www-data 11609 11607 0 16:01 ? 00:00:00 nginx: worker
process 
dev 11715 5885 0 16:16 pts/0 00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

========================================================================

Running `ls -l /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php` outputs:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dev dev 2 Feb 10 15:26 /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php
```

Comment: What user is nginx running under, and what are the access rights to your index.php ? Said in another way, does the user running nginx have assess to the index.php ?

Comment: I haven't given them any access if that's what you mean, its running on the user I created on installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: Apparently you dont know how your system is set up .. please run `ps -ef | grep nginx` and `ls -l /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php` in a terminal, and update your question with the output from both.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx run's as the user www-data. /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php is owned by user dev and in group dev,which both has read and write access. Others only have read access. No one has execute rights to the file.

Running `chmod +x /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php` should set execute rights for both owner, group and others .. you will see access rights like `-rwxrwxr-x` if you do a ls -l on the file again.

Also you might have to configure nginx to allow it to use /home/dev/Dropbox/www/ for data directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I'm still getting 404. Running `ls -l` on `index.php` again returns `-rw-rw-r-- 1 dev dev 2 Feb 10 15:26 /home/dev/Dropbox/www/index.php` , I also don't understand what you mean by your last sentence, maybe you could explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Running a website out of any home directory will cause problems.  Consider that to get into that directory, a user has to have read and execute ("traverse" for directories) permissions available to them on every folder in the access tree (`/home`, `/home/user/`, `/home/user/Dropbox/`, etc) until you reach the directory for the docroot itself.

This introduces a *lot* of security risk - if someone happens to hijack the webserver they will be able to traverse into your own home directory data without having to be superuser.

Any websites *should* be run outside of your actual home directory whether Dropbox'd or not.

You would need to do `sudo chmod +rx /home/ /home/user/ /home/user/Dropbox/ /home/user/Dropbox/www/` to properly let things access it, unless you start doing highly customized access rules.

(Note that Dropbox is *not* a sane way to backup/sync your site, because of the permissions problems it introduces like this...)

Comment: I receive `'chmod: changing permissions of '/home/': Operation not permitted` when trying to do this.

Comment: You may need to use `sudo` with the chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, you are using **php-fpm** with **nginx**. If this, you need to allow nginx user to write to php-fpm socket.

Edit file

> sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

uncomment option

> ;listen.mode  = 0600

set new value (it's allow all users write to php-fpm socket)

> listen.mode  = 0666

Restart php-fpm instance for apply changes

> sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart